# Sending HTTP request headers in C3.js to source URL

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, c3.js

I am using c3-angular.min.js. On client side, I have written a interceptor for adding authorization header to each request being sent to api server.
All http request seems to have authorization apart from ones which are made through C3.js. as result, my charts receives 401 error. Not much documentation is available.

how to add http request headers on requests made by c3.js.

```
 $scope.config={
            bindto: '#div1_chart',
            data: {
              'x':'x',
              'types':{'count':'area'},
              'names':{'count':'hits/day'},
              'url':$scope.base_url,
              'mimeType':'json'
            },
            axis : {
                x : {
                    type : 'timeseries',
                    tick : {
                rotate: 45,
                multiline: false,
                      fit: false,
                      format : $scope.format 
                    },
              height:100
                }
            }
        };
$scope.showGraph = function() {
    $scope.chart = c3.generate($scope.config);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just went through the code of the C3.js library and found an undocumented feature, which does exactly this. It is up to you if you want to rely on this, but it seems to work perfectly. I checked the most current code of the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/c3js/c3).

You can do this by adding a `headers` object to the `data` object or the object of the `load` function. Every key/value pair of the `headers` object will then be translated to a XMLHttpRequest request header. This is the relevant code of the library:

```
else if (args.url) {
    $$.convertUrlToData(args.url, args.mimeType, args.headers, args.keys, function (data) {
        $$.load($$.convertDataToTargets(data), args);
    });
}
```

and then inside `convertUrlToData()`:

```
if (headers) {
    Object.keys(headers).forEach(function (header) {
        req.header(header, headers[header]);
    });
}
```

So, an example of a request with headers in C3.js would look like this:

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        url: 'https://c3js.org/data/c3_test.csv',
        headers: {
            "testheader": "testvalue" 
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.2/c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.2/c3.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I also checked the source code, this looks fine, but somehow headers still not being added.

Comment: Go to this [link](http://c3js.org/samples/data_url.html) and open your browsers developer tools in the network view. Add the line `, headers: { "test": "test1" }` directly after the url line and check the headers in the network tab of the devtools. This will work.

Comment: @Sugam Any luck in solving this. I am struck in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

After some debug, I think I found a bug in C3.js.
C3.js uses fetch(url,options) for request, but options should be an object with "headers" **inside** it. So the working for me version of code is:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
    headers: {
      headers: {"testHeader": "test"}
    },
mimeType: 'json'
} });
```

I definitely see this test header in the network tab of the devtools now!
Also I believe you can add some more "fetch" options if you need.

Cheers!